# Mapping sampling sites on a map in R + creating a zoom in of a region in the same map

Tags: r, dictionary, mapping, coordinates

for my PhD project, I'd like to show my sampling sites (coordinates) on a map showing them first on a map of NZ and then  building a zoom in of the region (coordinates that I pick myself) to show the sampling sites in that specific region. I am very new to R and I am finding a bit frustrating.

I managed to build a map of NZ (code follows) but how can I add the data points on it and how can I create a zoom in of a certain region and adding data points on it as well??

```
    NZ <- map_data("nz",xlim = c(166, 179), ylim = c(-48, -34)) 
    ggplot() +
    geom_path(aes(long, lat, group=group), data=NZ, color="black") +
    coord_equal() +
    scalebar(NZ, dist = 100, dist_unit = "km", st.size=3, height=0.01, model = 'WGS84', transform =    TRUE)
```

Thanks to whoever will help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dunedin <- tibble(X=170.5, Y=-45 - 52/60, Text="Dunedin")
NZ <- map_data("nz",xlim = c(166, 179), ylim = c(-48, -34))
ggplot() +
  geom_path(aes(long, lat, group=group), data=NZ, color="black") +
  geom_point(data=dunedin, aes(x=X, y=Y), colour="blue") +
  geom_label(data=dunedin, aes(x=X, y=Y, label=Text), colour="blue", nudge_x=1) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image: Annotated plot of NZ]

Incidentally, `scalebar` isn't part of `ggplot2`, so your example isn't self-contained.  That's not a major issue here, but could be in another situation.

Comment: Thankss!!!! I will try to use it to plot all my sampling sites! This is really helpful!

Comment: Happy to have helped.  If you have lots of sites, [`ggrepel`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html) may be helpful.  If you're satisfied, please accept my answer, so others know you don't need any more help.

Comment: Actually I added them all with data.frame function and I plotted them all together. it worked perfectly. I dont know how to "accept" your answer though, I actually still need to find a way to create a zoom in of a certain area of interest.. but thanks again for this!

Comment: There are lots of examples of zooming maps online.  Just Google! The best solution for you will depend on exactly what you want.  The leaflet package [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/) and [here](https://leafletjs.com/examples.html) may also be useful.  [Sorry.  Should have mentioned that before.]  Data.frame is exactly the right way to extend my demo.  To accept an answer, just click the grey tick to the left.  You can only do it once on each question.

Comment: Yes, thanks again. I did google it few times, never worked but now that I have my map, I will focus on this. Thanks again.